# Programmatically setting major mode of buffer with emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, buffer, elisp, mode

I wish to programmatically set the major mode of a buffer. I have dug into the documentation, and the function `set-buffer-major-mode` only takes a buffer object. I am essentially looking for a function that takes a buffer object and a mode name.

Alternatively, I also tried using `auto-mode-alist` by forcing the buffer to have a file extension but that did not work even when I called the `set-buffer-major-mode` function.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The basics are that if you want to switch to `my` mode, all you have to do is to call `my-mode`, for example:

```
(with-current-buffer buffer
  (my-mode))
```

If you have a buffer and a variable bound to the major mode, you could use the following:

```
(with-current-buffer buffer
  (funcall the-mode-i-want))
```

Again, if you have a variable bound to a string, you have to convert it to a symbol using `intern`:

```
(with-current-buffer buffer
  (funcall (intern the-name-of-the-mode-i-want)))
```

Comment: @azzamsa, you should either use `(my-mode)` or `(funcall a-variable-holding-the-major-mode)`, but you should not mix the two variants.